# How facebook detects image with url in chat box

Tags: image, url

I want to add image which shown with my website url when the url posted in facebook chat box, or any website

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBjZf.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look around there https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters?locale=fr_FR

What you are looking for are the `<meta property="og:...">` tags

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i just want that when i write my url in facebook chat box, facebook automatically detects an image that represents my website. sample is attached with question in image form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBjZf.jpg

Comment: `<meta property="og:image" content="some-picture.jpg" />`